# Necessary to synchronize a concurrent HashMap when calling values()?

Tags: java, concurrency, hashmap

In the following code:

```
private final Map<A, B> entriesMap = Collections
  .synchronizedMap(new HashMap<A, B>());

// ...

List<B> entries = new ArrayList<>(this.entriesMap.values());
```

If `entriesMap` is being accessed/modified by multiple threads in other methods, is it necessary to `synchronize` on `entriesMap`? In other words:

```
List<B> entries;

synchronize (this.entriesMap) {
  entries = new ArrayList<>(this.entriesMap.values());
}
```

If I am correct, `values()` is not an atomic operation, unlike `put()` and `get()`, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that even if `values()` itself were atomic, the act of *iterating* over it is isn't. The `ArrayList` constructor can't take a copy of the values in an atomic way - and the iterator will be invalidated if another thread changes the map while it's copying them.

Answer (score 1):

Well, *calling* values might well be an atomic operation, but the Collection it returns is not a snapshot copy, but backed by the underlying Map, so it will croak when there are concurrent modifications to the Map as you iterate it *afterwards* (when copying it into the ArrayList).

Note that this (ConcurrentModificationException) also happens when there is just one thread, as long as you iterate the values and modify the Map in an interleaved fashion, so this is not really a problem of thread synchronization.

Further note that there is [ConcurrentHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html), which does provide for a snapshot iterator, that you can iterate while modifying the Map (modifications are not reflected in the iterator). But even with ConcurrentHashMap, the Collection of values() is not a snapshot, it works just like for the normal HashMap.

Comment: So in your example, with ConcurrentHashMap you would not need the synchronized block.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right.

When put the values of the map in the `ArrayList`, an iteration is performed on the values. So you need the synchronized block. See this [page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29).

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.synchronizedMap()` guarantees that each atomic operation you want to run on the map will be synchronized. and `values()` is also atomic , but when you are putting values to `ArrayList` that will not be synchronized in this case you need to synchronized the list also.